# use lm() to compute multivariate regression parameters, by response variable name

Tags: r

Overall goal is to call `lm(cbind(data$response1, data$response2) ~., data = data)`. When I use the `$`, the subsequent call to `~.` adds all variables in `data` as predictors but excludes `"response1"` and `"response2"`.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me figure out how to create a function that takes a data frame and a variable name and prints that variable. For example:

## (expected output)

```
    create.vector <- function(data, variable.name) {
        return(data$variable.name)
    }
    data <- iris
    head(
    create.vector(iris, "Species")
    )
[1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
```

I have tried to input the line paste(data, variable.name, collapse = "$"), but the output seems to remain of data type character...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is looking for a column literally called `variable.name` and there is no such column in `iris`.

For example, note that column `variable.name`, not the column called `Species` is returned here:

```
create.vector <- function(data, variable.name) {
        return(data$variable.name)
    }

DF <- data.frame(variable.name = 1, Species = 2)
create.vector(DF, "Species")
## [1] 1
```

What you want is:

```
return(data[[variable.name]])
```

Be sure to use double square brackets as single square brackets will return a data.frame with one column rather than a vector which is what it seems you want.

Also, although not wrong, we don't need the return keyword since a function always returns the last line in it that is executed so the `return` line could be just:

```
data[[variable.name]]
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `[[` and `$` can be used as function calls when enclosed in back ticks. I think that helped me improve my understanding of what was going on (e.g., `\`[[\`(iris, "Species")` and `\`$\`(iris, "Species")`

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! The issue is that I seek to then call: `lm(cbind(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length) ~., data = iris)`. When I use the `$`, the lm function knows to exclude `Sepal.Width` and `Sepal.length` as X variables specified by the `~.`. But the double brackets doesn't seem to solve that...

Comment: The answer responds to your question.  The problem in the comment is really different and you don't need square brackets or $ for that.  `f <- function(data, ...) { 
  fo <- sprintf("cbind(%s) ~.", paste(..., sep = ",")); 
  lm(fo, data)
};
f(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")`

Comment: Thank you, this last comment was very helpful actually and worked!

Answer (score 0):

**Update** per OP comments
Here's how to pass in two column names for the call to `lm()`:

```
create.vector <- function(data, v1, v2) {
  lm(cbind(data[[v1]], data[[v2]]) ~ ., data[,!names(data) %in% c(v1,v2)])
}
create.vector(iris, "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = cbind(data[[v1]], data[[v2]]) ~ ., data = data[, 
    !names(data) %in% c(v1, v2)])

Coefficients:
                   [,1]       [,2]     
(Intercept)         3.048497   3.682982
Petal.Length        0.154676   0.905946
Petal.Width         0.623446  -0.005995
Speciesversicolor  -1.764104  -1.598362
Speciesvirginica   -2.196357  -2.112647
```

**Original**
Square-bracket indexing `df[[col]]` is an alternative to indexing into a data frame with the dollar-sign (`$`) notation.  Here's a short review of [accessors in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-accessors-explained/).

```
create.vector <- function(data, variable.name) data[[variable.name]]

create.vector(iris, "Species")
       Species
1       setosa
2       setosa
3       setosa
...
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! The issue is that I seek to then call: `lm(cbind(iris$Sepal.Width, iris$Sepal.Length) ~., data = iris)`. When I use the `$`, the lm function knows to exclude `Sepal.Width` and `Sepal.length` as X variables specified by the `~.`. But the double brackets doesn't seem to solve that...

Comment: hi, see updated solution - the double-bracket approach seems to work.  what happens when you try it?

Comment: Hi, thank you again for updating your suggestion, but if you note in the output of the lm summary, sepal.width and sepal. length are included as predictors in addition to being V1 and V2 (response variables). I do not want to predict those variables with themselves...

Comment: This is just an indexing issue - remove the columns from the `data` argument.  I've updated with one way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There's a builtin, `getElement`

```
getElement(object=iris, name="Species")
# [1] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [7] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [13] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [19] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [25] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [31] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [37] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [43] setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa     setosa    
# [49] setosa     setosa     versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
# [55] versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor versicolor
# [61] ...
```